# Create web application framework with Maven

Tags: java, svn, web-applications, maven, project

we are trying to develop a web application framework and build implementatins on top of it. This framwork will be versioned in SVN, live its own life in parallel to those implementations. It will have lots of spring config files, security config and so on. We would like to use those in those implementations.

What structure should such an project have? Keep everything together? Link particular folers (implementations) in "svn: externals"? We would like to use Maven, and create an archetype for those implementations, but is it possible to update the archetype after it has been changed in implementation applications?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example :

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/web.html

Also this book is very useful resource when starting with maven

I found this also :

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-web-application-project-using-maven.html

Comment: @VoodooRider yes, if you have child projects, they will be packaged like a jar, so your parent war will have all of those under lib directory .. maven takes really good care of any dependencies as long as you specify them correctly.

Comment: @VoodooRider yes, the parent project doesn't necessary have to the end product, it can be any of the children as well. Maven is great once you give in to its philosophy and that is "convention over configuration".

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you create your framework project as a simple jar project to include in your implementation, which would be war projects. For the Spring config files you have three options then:

1. Package them into your framework jar. This would make it hard for the implementations to customize it. I would not recommend it, unless your configuration is definitively fixed.
2. Use svn: externals. I have not much experience with that, but I think dependencies between svn repositories would be hard to manage.
3. Maintain these configuration files per implementation. So, an archetype would help to get started with an initial configuration. Then maintain these configuration files as your framework evolves. This is what we do most of the time. The good thing about Spring configuration is that it often rarely needs to be touched once you are confident with it.

Comment: I would really prefer to have my framework project as war due to the ability to deploy it and serve as tutorial for new developers to learn